# What are the difference between "be about to do something" and "be going to do something"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, difference

Often these phrases are translated similarly. In which situation "be about to do something" more preferred? If I have the right understanding, this turnover is used then something will happen soon. But most often I met sentences like the following: "You are about to commit changes" (or make something else without extended context). I guess this is some impolite. Please, explain how to use this phrase.

Comment: 'Be about to...' is _only_ used when the action is expected to happen very soon. There is nothing impolite about it in itself, though of course it wouldn't be polite to say something like 'You're about to make a fool of yourself'.

Comment: Thank you, but why did you make a comment, not an answer? Unfortunately, I do not remember the specific example that outraged me. It looked like imposing my own decisions on me. It was something related to the announcement or advertising. But maybe I just took it that way.